# How do I search for PDF non-embed fonts?

Tags: google-docs, google, pdf, embed

I am trying to upload a pdf to KDP Amazon Publishing. My book was created in google docs. I save to print PDF and upload the paperback manuscript, but it has non-standardized fonts. How do I find the specific fonts? (T3Font_1057)

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Just to be clear... Would you please confirm that you installed and used Type 3 fonts in Google Docs? Would you please clarify whether you used the font throughout the text, or only in specific places? Would you please describe the length of the document and/or the number of locations that you used the font. Is your goal to locate the exact places in your Google Doc where the Type 3 fonts were used, and to change the style to use a font other than the Type 3 font? Have you considered using Adobe Acrobat to find and replace the Type 3 fonts?

Comment: FWIW, If you are uncertain where EVERY instance of the Type 3 font might be, then it _might_ be possible to write a script that would loop through the document and identify the Font-Family for each element.

Comment: @Tedinoz Hey Ted, thanks for helping! I can confirm that the Type 3 font is in my google document because I used Adobe Acrobat to figure out if the font was embed or not. My goal is to find where the Type 3 font because that's the core problem preventing me from uploading my document. Pages: 44; Words: 4187; Characters: 15397.

Comment: OK, but how/where/when was the font used? in Tables, text boxes, body text, etc. I'm trying to figure out how to winnow the haystack so that it easier to find the needle ;) BTW, are you familiar with apps script? If not, then you might have to post a short extract that can be used to find the font.

Comment: I don't know where the font was used? And I don't know how to use apps script either. I can share the document with you.

Comment: Hi.  I'm prepared to have a go to locate the font. I'm in Sydney (so there's probably/maybe a time difference). Make a copy of your original document. Open that copy, click the "blue" Share button. In the lower "Get the Link" box, make sure it says "Restricted: Only people added can open with this link", then click "Copy Link" and post the link here. To access the document, I will have to request permission from you, so that will stop any passer-by from accessing your document. Once the link is working and we can collaborate, you can delete the comment containing the link. OK?